# How to draw grouped bar chart in dimple js if x-axis is timeAxis and y-axis is measureAxis

Tags: dimple.js

Please help me out for drawing grouped bar chart in dimple js.

I have to draw the graph where x-axis is timeAxis and y-axis is measureAxis.

I have seen many code snippets when they have done this. But, i am unable to do this with x-axis as timeAxis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the time axis doesn't support grouping.  If you want to use dimple the only way is to use a category axis (which does work with time dimensions, but will evenly space and size each time value regardless of real interval).